# Less: development -> production routine

Tags: html, css, less

I am going to be using less now for the first time and I'm trying to setup my environment for it.

I currently have a source directory `~/www/src/` and a public `~/www/public/`

src is used for development and public for production.

How do I develop using less so that it is productive to me? As I see it it currently looks like this.

- For the development I must do the following:
  I must include `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="my-styles.less" />` *and* also include `<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
- For production I must compile the .less files to .css via gulp then remove `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />` and `<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and then add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my-styles.css" />`

This is kinda bulky. I would like to export my source into production without tinkering about my files. Does anyone have a good approach to this?

Comment: Run gulp continuously on your development environment with `gulp watch`.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks! All the tutorials I've been reading they missed that feature!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not make the browser evaluate the .less file. It is *possible*, but not very productive. The better way is to have a file watcher monitor your .less files and compile them to .css immediately as they are changed/saved. This only requires a little bit of setup on your development environment and no changes to the code itself or your deployment process. Depending on your editor/IDE such utilities may already be included; alternatively there are a ton of options for running such a watcher. Peruse the official LESS site for a list.

Comment: Perfect answer! I knew there was a way around this felt so impracticable.